# Is it possible to make a tooltip appear on a DotNetNuke menu?

Tags: menu, tooltip, dotnetnuke

I am running DNN 5.x and the XDMediaBlue skin in horizontal menu full mode. Is there any way to have a tooltip appear for menu items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look at jQuery  one of the tooltip plugins should be able to do this - not exactly sure how the tooltip info might be loaded in practice but i think it could be done without a lot of work maybe loading a json array of info after the page loads that the tooltip plugin could use

Here is one link to get you started - http://craigsworks.com/projects/simpletip/ and here is google to find a bunch of these - http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+tooltip&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a